# Dynamically display available months left in a select dropdown based on Year selected in another select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table that has the months from January to December with values 1 to 12. On my page i have a dropdown with years from current year. I also have another dropdown that displays the months.

By setting the current month, I can get the dropdown of months to display current month and the remaining month of the year. What I need help for is for the month dropdown to display available months remaining based on year selected from the year dropdwon. That is if I select 2019, I should see only December(current month and last month of year). If I pick 2020, I should see January to December.

I have checked other solutions, but it does not help with what I need. Some of the solutions seen have the month names as an array but the corresponding values are not included.

My php code below:

```
$curmonth = date('n');

$query = "SELECT calmonthsID, months, value from calmonths WHERE value>=? ORDER BY calmonthsID ASC";
$stmt = $connQlife->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $curmonth);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($calmonthsID, $months, $value);
```

The html code below:

```
<select name="year" id="year" value="" tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true" required style="height:50px;display: block;padding:10px;" class="h5">
   <option value="" selected="selected">- Select Year -</option>
   <option value="2019">2019</option>
   <option value="2020">2020</option>
   <option value="2021">2021</option>
   <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>

<select name="month" id="month" value="" tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true" required style="height:50px;display: block;padding:10px;" class="h5">
    <option value="" selected="selected">- Select One -</option>
    <?php while($stmt->fetch()) { ?>
        <option value=<?Php echo $value; ?>><?Php echo $months; ?></option>                             
    <?php } $stmt->close(); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: this is called a "cascading dropdown", if you want to google for solutions. You'll need JavaScript and AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AJAX, I may suggest following workaround:

1. Render all possible select-month inputs outside of the form with ids like `month-${year}` and set `style.display:none`.
2. In select-year input make onChange - copy (or move) needed select-month into form & unhide it.